# Need help getting RCON working on my Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

My Minecraft server's Rcon feature isnt working. I want to connect to it through my phone but it doesn't connect. The port 25575 is forwarded, so thats not the issue. I suspect that Rcon running on 0.0.0.0 is the issue but I dont know how to fix it. Help is appreciated!

```
Starting minecraft server version 1.14.1 
[12:49:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties 
[12:49:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL 
[12:49:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair

[12:49:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[12:49:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type 
[12:49:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world" 
[12:49:22] [Server thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default 
[12:49:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 6 recipes 
[12:49:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 811 advancements 
[12:49:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:overworld 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:32] [Server-Worker-3/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0% 
[12:49:33] [Server-Worker-2/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 15% 
[12:49:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 7730 ms 
[12:49:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (11.729s)! For help, type "help" 
[12:49:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting remote control listener 
[12:49:33] [RCON Listener #1/INFO]: RCON running on 0.0.0.0:25575
```

Comment: @dly no, that's my bad in the edit. Correcting it.

Comment: @M'vy alright, sorry. I'd still like to see the server.properties (or at least the relevant settings) to make sure there's no error in it.

Comment: That would probably help. Also, a step by step of what you are trying to do to initiate the RCON would help.

Answer (score -1):

You have to connect to the computer's ip address not 0.0.0.0. That's also the ip address you should have forwarded the port with.